# Close a MongoDB Tailable Cursor in JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb, api

I'm using a tailable cursor on a Capped Collection on MongoDB.
But when i'm trying to close it. The thread who wait on "hasNext()" is stuck forever. In the exemple I'm trying to retrieve all documents of a collection with a cursor. After 6 secs, an another thread closes the cursor.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = mongocollection.find().cursorType(CursorType.TailableAwait)
            .noCursorTimeout(true).iterator();
new Thread(() -> {
    // Wait for 6 seconds
    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Close the cursor
    cursor.close();
}).start();

try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursor.next();
        // do what you want with doc
        System.out.println(doc.toJson());
    }
} catch (MongoCursorNotFoundException e) {
   //OK, the cursor is closed
   e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("end");
```

I'm using the mongoDB java driver 3.4.2 with a mongoDB server 3.4

I tried with the CursorType.Tailable option but the net was flooded by requests like:
It works but the network is flooded by requests like that:

```
15:36:48.002 [Thread-366] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command {getMore : BsonInt64{value=43120971156}} to database smartrail on connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:253}] to server item-89671:27012
15:36:48.002 [Thread-366] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Command execution completed
```

Comment: what exactly is the quetion here?.  Be more specific

Comment: My problem is that my thread who iterate on the cursor is stucked on the instruction `cursor.hasNext()` even that the instruction cursor.close() was called.

Comment: Try to use Tailable as cursor type

Comment: It works but the network is flooded by requests like that: